# Bootstrap - custom nav-bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to do something very simple with bootstrap, I need to implement this navbar.

[image]

I know it's simple, but I tried to implement it with **pure** bootstrap classes.

This is the closest that I got (but I can't make the navbar background to blue):

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Customers</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#/about">Orders</a></li>
      <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
```

It is possible to implement it **only with** bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's kind of hacking the intended use of CSS classes...

```
    <div class="bg-primary well-sm"> 
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a ng-href="#" class="btn-primary">Customers</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#" class="btn-default">Orders</a></li>
        <li><a ng-href="#" class="btn-primary">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/evEpR2C7DV